tsc with skipLibCheck still check node_modules
I use cli npx tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck, it still raise err
node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1631:41 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

1631         keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
                                             ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1646:17 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1646         set(name: string, value: string): void;
                     ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1646:32 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

1646         set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                    ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1646:41 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1646         set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                             ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1646:47 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

1646         set(name: string, value: string): void;
                                                   ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1650:17 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1650         values(): IterableIterator<string>;
                     ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1650:43 - error TS1005: '(' expected.

1650         values(): IterableIterator<string>;
                                               ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1654:26 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1654         [Symbol.iterator]: typeof MIMEParams.prototype.entries;
                              ~

node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts:1656:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

1656 }
     ~


In tsconfig.json, I have set skipLibCheck:true, but tsc still check node_modules files
I upgrade typescript to 5.4.3, it fix
